# JavaScript -TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, tree

I am trying to create a tree and calculate its height.
The `map` array is initialised properly in the `for` loop but `console.log(map+"  this is map");` shows
 `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  this is map`. I am having problems accesing the children property in the second for loop at

```
map[list[i]]["children"].push(node);
```

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`
How to resolve this ??

The input is -

```
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

The first line contains the number of nodes . The second line contains  integer numbers
from −1 to  − 1 — parents of nodes. If the -th one of them (0 ≤  ≤  − 1) is −1, node  is the root,
otherwise it’s 0-based index of the parent of -th node. It is guaranteed that there is exactly one root.
It is guaranteed that the input represents a tree.

Code -

```
var readline = require('readline');

var input = [];
enter image description here
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', function (cmd) {
    input.push(cmd);
});

rl.on('close', function (cmd) {
   input=input[1].split(" ");
    console.log(list_to_tree(input));
    let tree1=list_to_tree(input);
    console.log("this   "+height(tree1));
    process.exit(0);
});


function list_to_tree(list) {
    var map = [], node, roots = [], i;
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        map.push({[i] :list[i],
            children:[]
        });
        console.log(map);

    } 
    console.log(map+"  this is map");
    for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        node=map[i];
        if(list[i]!==-1){
            console.log(map[list[i]]);
            map[list[i]]["children"].push(node);

        }
        else {
            roots.push(node);}
    }
    return roots;
}


function height(tree){
    if(tree===null){return 0;}

   let h=0;
    for(let x in tree){
        for (let y in tree[x]["children"]){
            h=Math.max(h,height(y));

        }
         return h+1;
    }



}
```

Comment: @PrashantGupta i have added the input format and the ss of output is https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRNbm.jpg and which json are u exactly asking for ??

Answer (score 0):

declare 'map' as array of object. Then use like this.

```
map.push({node})
```

I experienced the same issue and I did like this. list declared as array of object.

Comment: that would work but how would I access the children property to add children to the node.  map.push({node}) would simply push a node into map but I want to add that node as a child node to another node. Am i missing something in ur hint ??